# Can not set image resource of a custom imageview in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-paint

I have created a custom view project based on the lessons I have learned in [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-andoid-kotlin-training-custom-views/#0) and [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-canvas/#0). 
In my project, I tried to draw not just on a view but on a custom `ImageView`. Therefore, I have created a custom `ImageView` and did all the steps as in the mentioned official codelabs.
Here is my custom `ImageView` class:

```
// Stroke width for the the paint.
private const val STROKE_WIDTH = 12f

class MyImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var path = Path()
    private val drawColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorPaint, null)

    private lateinit var extraCanvas : Canvas
    private lateinit var extraBitmap : Bitmap

    private val touchTolerance = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop

    private var currentX = 0f
    private var currentY = 0f

    private var motionTouchEventX = 0f
    private var motionTouchEventY = 0f

    // Set up the paint with which to draw.
    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = drawColor
        // Smooths out edges of what is drawn without affecting shape.
        isAntiAlias = true
        // Dithering affects how colors with higher-precision than the device are down-sampled.
        isDither = true
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE // default: FILL
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND // default: MITER
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND // default: BUTT
        strokeWidth = STROKE_WIDTH // default: Hairline-width (really thin)
    }

    init{
        init()
    }

    private fun init(){


        setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener { _, event ->
            event?.let {
                motionTouchEventX = it.x
                motionTouchEventY = it.y

                when(it.action){
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> touchStart()
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> touchMove()
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> touchUp()
                }
                return@OnTouchListener true
            }
            false
        })
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.drawBitmap(extraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        if (::extraBitmap.isInitialized) extraBitmap.recycle()
        extraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        extraCanvas = Canvas(extraBitmap)
    }


    private fun touchStart() {
        path.reset()
        path.moveTo(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY)
        currentX = motionTouchEventX
        currentY = motionTouchEventY
    }

    private fun touchMove() {
        val dx = Math.abs(motionTouchEventX - currentX)
        val dy = Math.abs(motionTouchEventY - currentY)
        if (dx >= touchTolerance || dy >= touchTolerance) {
            // QuadTo() adds a quadratic bezier from the last point,
            // approaching control point (x1,y1), and ending at (x2,y2).
            path.quadTo(currentX, currentY, (motionTouchEventX + currentX) / 2, (motionTouchEventY + currentY) / 2)
            currentX = motionTouchEventX
            currentY = motionTouchEventY
            // Draw the path in the extra bitmap to save it.
            extraCanvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        }
        // Invalidate() is inside the touchMove() under ACTION_MOVE because there are many other
        // types of motion events passed into this listener, and we don't want to invalidate the
        // view for those.
        invalidate()
    }

    private fun touchUp() {
        // Reset the path so it doesn't get drawn again.
        path.reset()
    }
}
```

This is how my XML layout of the `MainActivity` looks like
(in the codelab there was no one, they just used the custom view programmatically):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.celik.abdullah.drawingonimageview.MyImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And here is my `MainActivity.kt` class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
    }
}
```

My problem is: the image resource is not shown on which I want to draw. 
The drawing part works like in the codelabs. But the `R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground` drawable which I wanted to use just for testing purposes is not shown on the screen. WHY ?

I hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the custom view, the canvas is only being used to draw the `extraBitmap` which is being updated by `extraCanvas` so `MyImageView` is only handling the drawing of `extraBitmap`.

`setImageResource` belongs to `ImageView` class which is internally handling the conversion of resource to drawable and drawing it on the canvas inside it's `onDraw()` but `onDraw` is being overridden by the custom view which is not handling the drawing of received bitmap so the solution is call `super.onDraw` as:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this to execute imageview's onDraw for image handling
    canvas?.drawBitmap(extraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
}
```

Alternately, you can `override` `setImageResource` and add the code to draw received resource via `setImageResource` method on the `canvas` inside `onDraw` of `MyImageView`.

Comment: Thanks :) It solved my problem. And a great explanation, by the way.

Comment: Thank you and I am glad that I could help. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it also by using `setBackgroundResource(..)`:

```
binding.myImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
```

So your MainActivity would look like:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.myImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
    }
}
```

Using a `purple` draw color the result would be something like this after drawing a bit and using `ic_launcher_foreground` as background image:

[image]

Don't forget, as suggested by @Pavneet_Singh:

> call super on the onDraw method you override (as in
>   super.onDraw(canvas))